# Listview custom ListItem template

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, adt

I'm new to Android programming,

**Product :**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class Product {
    private String Name;
    private byte[] Picture;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public byte[] getPicture() {
        return Picture;
    }
    public void setPicture(byte[] picture) {
        Picture = picture;
    }

    public Product(String Name) {
        this.setName(Name);
    }

}
```

---

**Products :**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
 public class Products extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Product> Products = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.products);
        Products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        Products.add(new Product("Ahmed"));
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.Products))
                .setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.product, R.id.Name, Products));

    }

    public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

        private List<Product> Products;

        public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<Product> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.Products = objects;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Products.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ProductHolder Holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product,
                        null);
                Holder = new ProductHolder();
                Holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
                Holder.Picture = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.Picture);
                convertView.setTag(Holder);
            } else {
                Holder = (ProductHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Product product = Products.get(position);
            if (product != null) {
                Holder.Name.setText(product.getName());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public static class ProductHolder {
        public TextView Name;
        public ImageView Picture;
    }
}
```

---

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.Ghoneim.Dealer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.Ghoneim.Dealer.Products"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**Issue :**

Just showing a white empty activity!

Comment: have u add activity into manifest file

Comment: yes, manifest added to question

Comment: down-voting me! I'm an android newbie, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you wrong at this line you are using the same layout in setContentView() and the each row's layout

```
  setContentView(R.layout.products);
```

use this way

```
 setContentView(R.layout.XML_FILE_WHICH_CONTAIN_LISTVIEW);
```

**EDIT** :

Just put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this xml name here like

```
R.layout.products
```

Comment: if you mean writing this, then R.layout.XML_FILE_WHICH_CONTAIN_LISTVIEW couldn't be resolved.

Comment: @Dixit The `products.xml` file is the one which contains the `ListView`. Check the OP; it's already posted...

Comment: if you mean the layout which contains a listview, then products layout has one !

Comment: Dixit Patel has a point, you are using the same layout in `setContentView()` and the each row's layout...

Comment: @Sam Huh? He's using `R.layout.products` for the content view and `R.layout.product` for the rows...

Comment: @Eric Ha, I missed the 's'. I must be tired.

Comment: it's working but why! as @Eric said it's product for row and productS for list

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the `ListActivity` class. Not the `Activity` class

Comment: then change your ListView id to "@android:id/list"

Comment: He don't need to extend ListActivity.

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim did u try changing your id to "@android:id/list" and changing the activity to ListActivity? You will also have to change findViewById(R.id.Products) to findViewById(android.R.id.list)

Answer (score 0):

try to change:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Products"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```